# What points go towards soldier levels and what points go toward class levels?

Tags: battlefield-1

In Battlefield 1, your soldier levels up based upon total points achieved during the round. However, I noted that the individual classes level up much slower.

What points or actions apply points toward your class levels (assault, scout, medic, support) vs your overall soldier level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the same experience is applied to both your class level and your overall soldier level (online player rank). The difference is caused by the difference in the total number of levels and experience.

[Player Rank](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Battlefield_1_Online_Ranks) goes up to 100, and requires 20,000,000 total experience.

Class level goes up to 10, and according to a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_one/comments/5avt72/class_ranks_xp_required/d9jrpi2/), the required experience is close to 45,000, but varies according to the class.

> Assault 50K
>   Medic 45K
>   Support 50K
>   Scout 30K
>   Pilot 25K
>   Tanker 60K
>   Cavalry 35K

Comment: If I understand this correctly, to go from level 0 to level 1 As assault I need 50K points, then another 50K to get to level 2, etc.